# Log4Net Referenced DLL and config file

Tags: .net, logging, error-handling, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a project (Project A) in Visual Studio that creates a generic error handling DLL (call it ErrorHandling.dll from now on). This has a reference to Log4net. On building this project i get my ErrorHandling.dll in the output directory along with the log4net.dll and the log4net.config file.

If i refer to the ErrorHandling.dll in another project (Project B) and build this project it outputs the ErrorHandling.dll and the log4net.dll but doesnt include the log4net.config therefore log4net does not work.

In Project A i have set the log4net.config file to Build Action: "Content" and Copy to Output Directory: "Copy Always"

Is there a way to force the config file to be included in the output directory of Project B when i run it?

Comment: It's more common to have the `log4net.config` file in/near the project of the actual executable application instead of the shared library in order to be adapted to the applications needs. Can you move it to that project?

Comment: Are project A en B within the same solution (.sln)?